# Openpyxl - Creating a chart on a different sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, excel-charts

I have been using Openpyxl to transfer pandas dataframes to an Excel file. I have to work utilising a template file given to me by work.

Because I cannot modify much in the 'printable' sheets, I created a worksheet at the end of the workbook where I added all of my dataframes. Now I must plot them and put the various charts in different sheets.

My question is, can I use openpyxl methods to create charts on sheets that are not active? All of the data/labels for the charts are on one sheet, and I want to make the graphs for different sheets. I have searched all of the documentation and this site and cannot find the answer.

An alternative question is, can I copy charts from one sheet to another within the same file? and if so, how can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can create charts on non-active sheets. 
Instead of using `active` you can use fixed references to each sheet, e.g.

```
wb = Workbook()
ws_data = wb['Data']
```

I always use worksheets like this (`Explicit is better than implicit`).

Example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series

wb = Workbook()
wb.create_sheet('Data')

ws_data = wb['Data']
for i in range(10):
    ws_data.append([i])

sheetlist = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3']

for w in sheetlist:
    wb.create_sheet(w)

for s in sheetlist:

    values = Reference(ws_data, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
    chart = BarChart()
    chart.add_data(values)

    ws = wb[s]
    ws.add_chart(chart, "B5")

wb.save("SampleChart.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I am not at work now but will try it tomorrow. I will give it a shot. I guess adding various different charts based on different dfs (like I have to) might be a bit tedious but if it works then its all good! :)

Comment: You can probably automatize most of it if there is some pattern which df needs which chart.